# cleopatra's problems

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $\int{\frac{9x+6}{(3x-2)^4(x+2)^4}dx}$

Comment: Let me [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%289x%2B6%29%2F%28%283x-2%29^4%28x%2B2%29^4%29+dx) it for you.

Answer (score 3):

$u=(3x-2)(x+2)=3x^2+4x-4$

$u'=6x+4=\frac{2}{3}(9x+6)$

$\displaystyle A=\int{\frac{3}{2}\frac{u'}{u^4}dx}=\frac{3}{2}\int{u^{-4}du}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{-1}{3}u^{-3}+c=\frac{-1}{2u^3}+c=-\frac{1}{2(3x-2)^3(x+2)^3}+c$